# Textarea content is not included in $_POST array sometimes, but is at other times.

Tags: php, jquery, textarea

I have been developing my own CMS for my own website. Just to test out PHP.
Anyway, everything was working fine and then all of a sudden I had this problem entering content for articles.

I am using the JQuery markItUp plugin for text editing purposes. It was working and then all of a sudden the main article wouldn't enter into the database.

Here is the form :

```
 <form action="" method="post" name="action">
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="title" >Article Title </label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="title" class="admintableinput"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="author" > Author </label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="author" class="admintableinput"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="summary" > Summary </label></td>
                        <td><textarea name="summary" class="admintableinput"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="content" >Article Content </label></td>
                        <td><textarea name="content" id="default" class="admintableinput"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="Category1" > Category </label></td>
                        <td><select name="Category1" id="category1" class="admintableinput">
                            <?php $categories = getCategoryNames();
                            foreach($categories as $category){  ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo "" . $category['id'] . "" ; ?>"><?php echo "" . $category['category'] . "" ; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="image" > Image </label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="image" class="admintableinput"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>                    
                        <td><input type="submit" name="action" value="Save Article" class="adminbutton" /></td>
                        <td><input type="reset" formnovalidate name="action" value="Reset" class="adminbutton"  /></td>
                    </tr>   
                </table>
            </form>
```

I have used var_dump($_POST) with and without the plugin.
With the plugin var_dump doesn't register the article content and without it it does. It always contains values in every other field.

Does anybody have any idea why this could happen?

I've tried completely removing and adding the plugin again.

Could this be an issue with the textarea?

Any help is appreciated. I don't think this is a PHP issue.

Comment: Have you tried changing the name and ID of the field? Probably a name clash as "content" is a common word. So call it "ArticleContent" or something?

Comment: I have changed the name to articlecontent and it still didn't work. I changed the id. No Luck. It only happens with the plugin. It was working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that, your javascript does not fill content into the textarea when form submitting.

You should to install an HTTP Debug Proxy named [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what had been submitted to PHP script.

Comment: I have installed fiddler and it is connecting too the localhost, could you tell me how to see what is being submitted. print_r shows that the textarea isn't even recognised by the $_POST array

Comment: 1. Choose the session(http request) in the left column of fiddler 2. Click the "Inspectors" tab oh the right column of fiddler, you will see two part in right column: the top one and the bottom one. the top one is Request, and the bottom is Response. 3. In the top part, click "WebForms"(or TextView, or Raw, WebForms is more human-readable) to see what you have submitted to the server side.