# Javascript (JQuery) does not fill content into the textarea when form submitting

Tags: php, javascript, markitup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Textarea content is not included in $_POST array sometimes, but is at other times.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240649/textarea-content-is-not-included-in-post-array-sometimes-but-is-at-other-time)

I have a form which is sent by POST, in it I have a textarea. Here is the code

```
<textarea name="content" id="default" class="admintableinput" cols="80" rows="20"></textarea>
```

I have used the markItUp plugin for text editing. When the plugin is used on the textarea it doesn't enter any content into the $_POST array.

I then tried a var_dump($_POST) and got this when the plugin was used:

```
Array ( [title] => title [author] => author [summary] => summary [Category1] => 3 [image] => image [action] => Save Article )
```

When the plugin isn't used var_dump produces this:

```
Array ( [title] => title [author] => author [summary] => summary [content] => content [Category1] => 4 [image] => image [action] => Save Article )
```

So any content entered into the textarea is only submitted without the plugin. But I have no idea why in the var_dump it doesn't even know there is a textarea there.

It must be a Javascript issue, I'm using the JQuery library.

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to rename the textarea to something else than `content`

Comment: correct me if i am wrong. the value of name and id attributes should be same right?

Comment: @Dr.Molle. This is not a duplicate. I have read all the other questions on here that have something to do with this subject.

Comment: @Connor Atherton: It's a duplicate of your own question, asked 13hours ago.

Comment: @mycholan Not necessarily. They're two different attributes.

Comment: @Dr.Molle - I did ask a similiar question last night, It was early in the morning. I used that answer, I have been debugging for hours. This is a question about why it wouldn't show up in the var_dump. Sorry If I've wasted your time

Comment: Also, I've went through the questions I've asked and gave proper recognition. I was just +1ing the answer instead of clicking the green tick.

Comment: You may post the same question over and over, so far we didn't got any code related to the plugin, only a crystal ball will help right now.

Comment: @Dr.Molle -I posted here because I was stuck on a problem. I thought someone might help me, there is a lot of code in the plugin and I don't know which bit to post. I was thinking if I could realise why the textarea isn't showing up in var_dump then I could fix it. It might help If you keep an open mind, realise I haven't been coding for the web for long and cut me some slack, I'm really frustrated and I just wanted a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: We may help you, when you help us to help you.  I was testing the plugin, it works as expected, so the issue must be a wrong implementation(but we don't have any informations about your implementation)

Comment: @Dr.Molle - I have used the default set and this is the code    $('#default').markItUp(mySettings); The editor appears on the textarea and all the features work. I have used the JSON file provided in the plugin download. My JQuery is in an external file. Hope this helps. Thanks a lot for trying to help me out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I will just delete everything and start again. Thanks for your time

Comment: What content do you try to send?

Comment: @Dr.Molle - I just tested it on a different form and it worked fine. I've transferred it onto a live site, if I give you a login do you want to have a look at it?

Answer (score -1):

I think that your plugin doesn`t set value for your textarea. Check for this.

Comment: The plugin was working fine. Then it stopped entering. So I deleted it from htdocs and downloaded and configured it again and still had the same problem. If it didn't set a value for textarea would it still show in var_dump but just be  : [content] =>     . Meaning that content was entered into $_POST but it was just empty? Thanks for your suggestion